# How to add Single-field Exemptions in Firestore Index Config File

Tags: database, firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

Please let me know how to add Index exemptions for Single-field, in the firebase-indexes.json file, in order to deploy through CLI.

Currently, below is my index config in the file firebase-indexes.json, able to deploy through CLI, but it is creating an index of type Composite, not as a Single-field Exemption.

```
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "comments",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "id",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "id",
          "order": "DESCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For later reference, the syntax of firestore index file is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/firestore/indexes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your collection is called "comments" and your exemption field is called "field", you will add a new property to your firestore.indexes.json called "fieldOverrides", like this:

```
{
  "indexes": [
    // your indexes here
  ],
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "comments",
      "fieldPath": "field",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "DESCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP"
        },
        {
          "order": "DESCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP"
        },
        {
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it got enabled only in "Collection scope", but I want this to be enabled for "Collection group scope" so that I can run my collection group query like:
"fdb.collectionGroup('comments').where('id', 'in', [<comment_ids>]).get()
.then{..}".   Currently, this query is failing.

Comment: OK, that would have been helpful to state in your question.  Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this question has been answered. Anyway, I want to bring an example for those who are working with firebase.

I got an error on production:
`The query requires a COLLECTION_GROUP_ASC index for collection invites and field code.  That index is not ready yet. See its status here https://console.firebase...`

The link provided created a ['Single-field index exemption'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#single-field_index_exemptions) automatically.

This is what I got on the Firebase Console:
[image]

And this is what I wrote on the `firebase.indexes.json` file:

```json
{
  "indexes": [
    // ...
  ],
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "invites",
      "fieldPath": "code",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
          "order": "DESCENDING"
        },
        {
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS"
        },
        {
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/firestore/indexes/#fieldoverrides) is the reference for FieldOverrides array in the indexes file.

I deleted the single-field index exemption through the Firebase Console and then I saved the file and deployed the project to create the single-field index exemption through CLI and CI/CD.